# How to demonstrate the gamblers fallacy

Tags: matlab

I'm beginning to learn Matlab and having trouble with a routine exercise which reads as follows

set ff to a null set, set x to equal 10,000 random numbers between 0 and 1  (make sure the numbers are rounded to the nearest integer) 
{Think of 1’s as Heads and 0’s at Tails} 
start a for loop where n goes to 9,999 coin flips (starting with the 4th flip)      check if the nth flip == Heads and if the previous three flips were also Heads          if so, save the result of the very next flip in your expanding vector ff    end the if statement 
end the for loop develop a way to check if half (or more than half) of those “fifth-flips” are tails. 
so far I have managed to get the beginning of the code seen below

clear

ff=[]

x=round(rand(1,10000)

for n=4:9999

```
    if n==1
```

not sure where to go from here, hoping for code with a thorough description of the reasoning behind command choices

Comment: Please read [ask]. You're asking us to do your homework for you, and explain it all as well. You're better off asking a more specific question, for example: "I have an array with 10,000 random numbers, how do I find sequences of 3 consecutive 1s?". Of course, first Google that question, surely it's been answered before. Take the exercise step by step, and find the solution to each step.

Comment: FYI. You can use the `randi` command to generate random integers, without needing to use `round` around it.